# Definition of regular singular point of ordinary differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, frobenius-method

I am studying the Frobenius method to solve series solution of differential equations around a regular singular point. I am using a book by an Indian author which defines the definitions as follows:

> Consider the general homogeneous second order linear differential equation $$y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0$$
> Then the point $x_0\in D$ is said to be an ordinary point of the above the given differential equation if $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are analytic at $x_0$. If either $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$ fails to be analytic at $x_0$, the point $x_0$ is called a singular point of the given differential equation.
>
> Further a singular point $x_0$ of the given differential equation is said to be a regular singular point if the functions $(x−x_0)P(x)$ and $(x−x_0)^2Q(x)$ are analytic at $x_0$ and irregular otherwise.

Now the following question was asked in my exam:

> *Question*: Determine how many linearly independent solutions does the
> differential equation $$x^2y''+3\sin(x)y'+y=0$$ have around X=0?

The above questions creates a confusion in my mind:

- Here $P(x)=\frac{3\sin x}{x^2}$ and $Q(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ and hence we have function $(x−x_0)P(x)=\frac{3\sin x}{x}$ and $(x−x_0)^2Q(x)=1$ then clearly $\frac{3\sin x}{x}$ is not analytic at $x=0$? So it means by definition 0 is irregular singular point, right? then how can we talk about series solution by Frobenius method around x=0, as we talk Frobenius method about regular singular point.
- Secondly, what is the answer to this question (i.e how many linearly independent solutions does given differential equation has?

Any help would be appreciable!

Comment: $\frac {3 \sin x} x$ (defined to be $3$ when $x=0$) is analytic at $x=0$

Comment: But it is not exactly analytic at x=0 as x=0 is removable singularity,and what about second question?

Comment: The leading indicial equation is $0=r(r-1)+3r+1=(r+1)^2$. This gives the basis solutions as perturbations of $x^{-1}$ and $x^{-1}\ln(x)$, of which neither exists at $x=0$. So what exactly does the question ask, are there examples presented that the task can be compared to?